# How To Get Total Prices From ListView Collection in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, shopping-cart

I've been looking online for a simple solution but can't seem to find any.

I simply want to generate a total price from all the item prices in my listview collection but can't seem to figure out how to do this.

How do I add all the product prices in my list and output them onto the total label?

Here's my code:

```
public ViewFBShoppingCart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<FBProduct> fbproducts = new ObservableCollection<FBProduct>();
            shoppingcartlistview.ItemsSource = fbproducts;

            var producttitle = "Apple";
            var productprice = "$37.95";
            var productimage = "image link goes here";

            var producttitle2 = "Pear";
            var productprice2 = "$32.95";
            var productimage2 = "image link goes here";

            fbproducts.Add(new FBProduct
            {
                ProductName = producttitle,
                ProductPrice = productprice,
                ProductImage = productimage
            }); 

            fbproducts.Add(new FBProduct
            {
                ProductName = producttitle2,
                ProductPrice = productprice2,
                ProductImage = productimage2
            });


        }
```

Comment: You generally dont, you usually query the underlying collection. Also we usually keep our numeric types as numeric types and not strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not using formatted string like "$35.00" you can format it later using `Text="{Binding ProductPrice, StringFormat='${0}'}` in your `.xaml` file

But in that case: You can use `Linq`

```
string total = fbproducts.Select(a => new { Converted = Convert.ToDouble(a.ProductPrice.Replace("$", "")) }).ToList().Sum(a => a.Converted).ToString("#,0.00");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code worked! FLAWLESS VICTORY!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are following MVVM pattern, first subscribe to your collection's event `fbproducts.CollectionChanged += fbproducts_CollectionChanged` and then inside that method based on `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` each time an item is added or removed you should raise the property changed event of a new readonly property that computes the sum using a loop or a 1-line Linq.

```
    private void fbproducts_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add || e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PriceSum));
        }
    }

    public decimal PriceSum => fbproducts.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.ProductPrice.Substring(1)));
```

You should also consider changing `ProductPrice` type to `decimal` instead of `string`.

Comment: Amazing thank you so much! The total worked ,I'm in the process of integrating the property changed event.

Answer (score 1):

```
string TotalProductPrices(ObservableCollection<FBProduct> fbproducts)
{
    var total = fbproducts.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.ProductPrice, NumberStyles.Currency));
    return total.ToString("c");
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for this! :)